# Rails render json to AngularJS frontend. Time becomes 00:00:00

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I'm using Rails' render method to pass rendered json to the AngularJS frontend. The dates got successfully passed. When I try `puts` in the backend, the rendered json  object also has the correct time. But for some reason all the time becomes 00:00:00 in the frontend.

Code in Rails backend:

```
... // a lot of other stuff

respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render json: @entries
  end
end
```

Code in AngularJS frontend:

```
XXX.query(params).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  ...
  // a lot of other stuff
}
```

Part of the response printed out in the backend:

```
[{"id":101752,"version":1,"date":"2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","date_created":"2018-06-02T01:56:44.000Z","last_updated":"2018-06-02T01:56:44.000Z"},{"date":"2018-06-04T00:00:00.000Z","date_created":"2018-06-05T03:36:14.000Z","last_updated":"2018-06-05T03:36:14.000Z"}]
```

You can see that the timestamps all have the time (except for the "date" where it's just supposed to have 00:00:00 for the time). However, when it gets to the frontend all the timestamps just become 00:00:00.

Part of the response printed out in the frontend:

[JSON response frontend print out.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aW1g.png)

Right now the only way I know to fix this is to add a function in the serializer for every timestamp using strftime(). It will convert the timestamps to strings before they get converted to JSON. But it would be VERY inefficient since I need to add strftime() function to every serializer for every timestamp. Does anyone have a better solution? Also, does anyone know what is really going on with the rails render method and the timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
AngularJS frontend does not recognize the default date format in JSON rendered by Rails.
In `config/initializer/ams.rb` file, you can turn off the standard JSON time format by adding the line `ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = false`.
This will affect existing frontend datetime format but it successfully enables AngularJS to recognize the TimeWithZone rendered in JSON by Rails.